# Adding CHAPTER line to contents with suppressed page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to add a line under "Contents" that says "CHAPTER" and suppress the page number associated with the line (additionally with List of Figures). That is, the page should look like:

Contents

CHAPTER

1. First Chapter...1
2. Second Chapter....2

List of Figures

FIGURE

1. fig x....1
2. fig y....2

I've tried the following. I realize that using the *section* formatting will provide the page numbers as default. Is there a way to turn them off individually? Or, is there someway to have the Contents span two lines where the first is Contents and the second is CHAPTER? Or is there a way to add content to the toc and specify the format inline?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is a test...

\tableofcontents{}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CHAPTER}

\listoffigures


\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{FIGURE}

and this is after the table of contents

\section{This is a section}

One two three

\section{this is the second section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, need to modify the `addcontentsline` to `addtocontents` as provided below.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline{section}{CHAPTER}{}}

\listoffigures

\addtocontents{lof}{\contentsline{section}{FIGURE}{}}

\section{First Section}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\caption{First Figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\section{Second Section}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\caption{Second Figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---